# How to Show Different Menus to Different User Roles in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide `Downloads` from Woocommerce menu when user type is Artist.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $role = ( array ) $user->roles;
        if($role[0]=="artist") // change role name if different
            unset($items['downloads']);
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_my_account_menu_items' );
```